# Power BI - create link visual

Tags: powerbi

We’ve developed a custom visual which includes an `<a>` tag stretched out along the whole visual body (something like imagebutton). By clicking on the `<a>` container, the user should be navigated to another PowerBI report. Our solution works in the Power BI developer tools, but we’re experiencing some problems when we use the exported visual in Power BI:
The Link doesn’t work in browsers, probably because of **sandboxing**, which is not happening in dev tools.

Can we disable the sandboxing? Alternatively, how can we create an "Image-Button"-Visual, which navigates to another report?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable sandboxing by adding this querystring:

```
?sandboxVisualsEnabled=false
```

This removes the iFrame and doesn't use Sandboxing.

Also try the new visuals that have just been released, you may have more success:
[PowerBI Visuals Docs](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals-docs)

Comment: where do I put sandboxVisualsEnabled=false?